# EF Core - Fluent API many-to-many self reference

Tags: ef-fluent-api, ef-core-2.0

I am attempting to configure 2 classes fluently.

```cs
public class Company 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CompanyOwnership> OwnedBy { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyOwnership 
{
    public static void Configure(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyOwnership>()
            .HasOne(cpo => cpo.OwnedCompany)
            .WithMany(cp => cp.OwnedBy)
            .HasForeignKey(cpo => cpo.OwnedCompanyId);    
        modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyOwnership>()
            .HasOne(cpo => cpo.OwningCompany)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(cpo => cpo.OwningCompanyId);
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public int OwnedCompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company OwnedCompany { get; set; }
    public int OwningCompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company OwningCompany { get; set; }
    public decimal Percentage { get; set; }
}
```

The above code will result in an error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the relationship
>       represented by navigation property 'Company.OwnedBy' of type
>       'List<CompanyOwnership>'. Either manually configure the relationship,
>       or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using
>       'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Could I get some input about why the above setup is not enough?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Nvm,

it turned out that I forgot to call Configure(...).

It is working fine now.